# Vim is missing on Lion

Tags: mac, vim

I uninstalled brew and macports and reinstalled homebrew. I dont have vi under /usr/bin/ anymore. How can I fix this?

I tried using brew to install it but it says

```
Error: No available formula for vi
Apple distributes vi with OS X, you can find it in /usr/bin.
```

Comment: `vi` vs `viM`, intentional?

Comment: Did you delete it at some point?

Comment: `/usr/bin/vi` is just a symlink to `vim` in the same directory.

Comment: I didnt have vi or vim in /usr/bin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of searching around this worked for me:

```
brew install https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-dupes/master/vim.rb
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have Macports then use:

> sudo port install vim

Comment: The OP said they uninstalled MacPorts and now use Homebrew, but that wouldn't bring back the system default vi

Comment: Actually they said, "I uninstalled brew and macports and reinstalled."
Which, because of the bad use of commas could very well mean they had brew and macports and reinstalled them both.

Comment: yeah, sorry about being unclear on that. Im using Homebrew now.

Comment: Okay, I searched my /usr/bin folder and found that vi is an alias to vim, as expected. So, now my question is, do you have VIM installed. Try to run that command.